# SQlite user defined function in python

Tags: python, sqlite, user-defined-functions

Because SQLite has problems with upper() and lower() with german umlauts, I need to create a user function in python.

Problem:
Data in SQlite:
address -> Elsa-Brändström-Str. nn
address.upper() -> ELSA-BRäNDSTRöM-STR. nn <-- still small umlauts "ö" and "ä"

Same problem for capital letters if I call lower().
The umlauts just won't change their casing with lower() and upper().

So I can't search for upper WHERE-Clause from my GUI... :-/

I've tried to follow this steps as a first test:
https://dzone.com/articles/adding-function-sqlite-python

But always get
"sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception"

How could such a "LIKE-"like py-function look like?

SQLite3
python 3.7.1

Comment: Look into building and loading the ICU extension module.

Comment: @shawn. thanks, was able to create the .so file for Linux.
Do you have a DLL for Windows which you could share? Or a simple instruction how to achieve this on Windows? Windows cannot load the so-file.

Answer (score 1):

use `u'ÅÄÖABC'` to show it's a unicode string

```
>>> u'ÅÄÖABC'.lower()
'åäöabc'
```

and

```
>>> u'åäöabc'.upper()
'ÅÄÖABC'
```